# I want to install "MahaSecure" Banking software in ubuntu 16.4

Tags: software-installation

i am a newbie please guide to install "MahaSecure" Banking software for Linux. 
I have download a File MahaSecure.tar.gz extract 3 directory (bin,Resource, Shared)
But now don't have any idea what to do next. Please Guide.

Comment: Can you provide the link from where you downloaded the software?

Comment: Bank of Maharashtra's FAQ says a funny thing: *Supported on all operating systems - Windows, MacOS, iOS, Android* . Technically it includes Linux (Android) but I read it as the usual support for desktop Windows and Mac plus mobile platforms. Are you sure you got that software from a reputable source, knowing the only reputable source in this case is the bank itself?

Answer (score 5):

Download link for Linux is visible only when you first login through their old net banking system.

Download & extract `MahaSecure-64Bit.tar.gz` for Linux in some folder, say `ABCD`. It contains one file `MahaSecureInstaller.sh` & a folder `MahaSecure.tar.gz` . Open `ABCD` in the terminal and type:

```
sudo ./MahaSecureInstaller.sh
```

This should install MahaSecure with a Desktop shortcut from where you can launch it.